# ActionResult Create with conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

im doing an MVC with CRUDS. 
this is my code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "FileStatusID, Name, MinValue, MaxValue")] fileStatusModel FILeStatusModel, TBL_FileStatus tBL_FileStatus) //include tem os valores que vamos inserir na view
{
    var userID = ((SessionModel)Session["SessionModel"]).UserID; // get current user id


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TBL_FileStatus item = new TBL_FileStatus()
        {
            Name = FILeStatusModel.Name,
            MinValue = FILeStatusModel.MinValue,
            MaxValue = FILeStatusModel.MaxValue,
            Ative = true,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            CreateBy = userID
        };

        db.TBL_FileStatus.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

I want to create a status with special conditions. 
I have a table with `ID`, `status`, `minvalue` and `maxvalue` and have an interval of numbers in those values.
I want to create another status out of the range of those numbers.

> ex: minvalue: 20 maxvalue: 40

So.. When i create a new status, if i put numbers inside that range, its say a message like "already exist in that range", if not, it creats de status.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1. Rendering layout page from ActionResult (using Controller. View extension method)**

> The Controller. View method has two extension methods, using these
>   extension methods we can pass a master page (layout page) name and
>   render a layout page based on a condition.
>   [image]

[image]

**Example Code**

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View("About","_otherLayout");
} 

public ActionResult OtherAbout()
{
    string myName = "Jignesh Trivedi";
    return View("About", "_otherLayout", myName);
}
```

**2. Using _ViewStart.cshtml Page**

> The Controller. View method has two extension methods, using these
>   extension methods we can pass a master page (layout page) name and
>   render a layout page based on a condition.
>
> Using the _ViewStart.cshtml page, we can change the layout page based
>   on a condition.

**Example Code**

```
@{   
var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    string layout = "";
    if (controller != "Home")
    {
        layout = "~/Views/Shared/_otherLayout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    Layout = layout;
}
```

> We can also create multiple _ViewStart.cshtml pages. The file
>   execution is dependent upon the location of the file within the folder
>   hierarchy and the view being rendered. The MVC Runtime will first
>   execute the code of the _ViewStart.cshtml file located in the root of
>   the Views folder.

[image]

**3. Define the Layout page in each view**

> We can override the default layout rendering by setting the Layout
>   property of the View using the following code.

```
@{   
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_otherLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}
```

As presented in the article by : Jignesh Trivedi at
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/rendering-layouts-base-on-condition-in-Asp-Net-mvc/